# Integration Test (E2E): How to check message on Azure Event Grid with NodeJS?

Tags: c#, node.js, typescript, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have a .NET HttpTrigger Azure Function which takes the request body and emit it to an Azure Event Grid topic.

I need to write an E2E or integration test for this in NodeJS/TS.  My thought is to mimic a HTTP Post request to the Azure function and then check/observe the message exists within the EventGrid topic as a check condition but that is easier said than done.

I found a [very cool project in .NET](https://eventgrid.arcus-azure.net/Features/running-integration-tests) but unfortunately I cannot use it because my test project is using PlayWright and NodeJS.

This Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-http-requests-node-get-started) talks about create a Node client/server using Azure Relay Connection.  But, I am not sure how to incorporate it into my test, or even if it is the right thing to do?

```
  import  { test as base, APIResponse } from '@playwright/test';

  let _respStatus: number;
  let _response: APIResponse;

  //Trigger the Azure Function
  base.step('Send POST to \"admin/functions/FunctionName\"', async () => {
    _response = await request.post('admin/functions/FunctionName',{ data: null });
    _respStatus = _response.status();
  });

  //Check for the message on Event Grid Topic via Azure Relay
  base.step("Listen for Event Grid message", async () => {
    const https = require("hyco-https");
    const ns = "{RelayNamespace}";
    const path = "{HybridConnectionName}";
    const keyrule = "{SASKeyName}";
    const key = "{SASKeyValue}";

    var uri = https.createRelayListenUri(ns, path);
    var server = https.createRelayedServer(
      {
        server: uri,
        token: () => https.createRelayToken(uri, keyrule, key),
      },
      (req, res) => {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        res.end("<html><head><title>Hey!</title></head><body>Relayed Node.js Server!</body></html>");
      }).listen(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.  Here is the general idea behind my solution.

- Create an Azure Relay on Azure cloud, create a hybrid connection and have it subscribed to the
  Event Grid to receive my test messages.
- Write a 'server' using nodeJs
  to hook into the Azure Relay in order to receive data.  In this case
  the Azure Relay acts as a client which sends request message to the
  server code.
- Wrap this server code inside the test.beforeAll() in my
  Playwrite test case so that each time the test run, this http server
  will start listening.
- When this 'server' receives message from Azure Relay, it parses
  the message and set any variable such as the message Id
  which I can use later in my test validation.

  ```
  test.beforeAll(async ({ getFunctionAppApiContext, a0UserCredentials }) => 
  {
      let _response: APIResponse;
      let _respBody: any;
      let respId: string;
      let server: any;
      var qs = require('querystring');
      let eventGridMessage: string;

    const https = require("hyco-https");

    const ns = '<relay_name>.servicebus.windows.net';
    const path = '<hybrid_connection_name>';
    const keyrule = '<hybrid_connection_policy_name>';
    const key = '<hybrid_connection_key>';

    //setup the listener to listen events from Azure Relay
    var uri = https.createRelayListenUri(ns, path);
    server = https.createRelayedServer(
    {
        server: uri,
        token: () => https.createRelayToken(uri, keyrule, key),
    },
    //process request from Azure relay originated from event grid 
    (req, res) => {
       var bodyStream = '';
       req.on('data', function(incomingData) {
           bodyStream += incomingData;
       });

       req.on('end', () => {
      eventGridMessage = qs.parse(bodyStream);
     });
    }).listen();
  });
  ```

The details that I based my solution on can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-http-requests-node-get-started